# how to use oracle instr function in java

Tags: java

```
if instr(lv_my_name, '  ', -2) != length(lv_my_name) - 2 or length(lv_my_name) = 2 then
    lv_my_name:= lv_my_name;
else
    lv_my_name:= trim(substr(lv_my_name, 0, length(lv_my_name)-1));
end if;
```

if I were to write the same logic in Java, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`INSTR(string, substring [, position [, occurrence] ] )`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF00651)

> The `INSTR` functions search `string` for `substring`. [...] If a substring that is equal to `substring` is found, then the function returns an integer indicating the position of the first character of this substring. If no such substring is found, then the function returns zero.
>
> `position` is an nonzero integer indicating the character of `string` where Oracle Database begins the search—that is, the position of the first character of the first substring to compare with `substring`. If `position` is negative, then Oracle counts backward from the end of `string` and then searches backward from the resulting position.
>
> `occurrence` is an integer indicating which occurrence of `substring` in `string` Oracle should search for. The value of `occurrence` must be positive. If `occurrence` is greater than 1, then the database does not return on the first match but continues comparing consecutive substrings of `string`, as described above, until match number `occurrence` has been found.

Compare that to:

[`String.indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-)

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified substring, starting at the specified index, or -1 if there is no such occurrence.

[`String.lastIndexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.String-int-)

> Returns the index of the last occurrence of the specified substring, searching backward from the specified index, or -1 if there is no such occurrence.

So, since your code doesn't use 4th parameter, and the 3rd parameter is negative, `INSTR` and `lastIndexOf` are mostly equivalent

Remember that Java indexes are 0-based, and Oracle positions are 1-based.